# How can I upgrade cloud-init?

Tags: cloud-init

I am working on Ubuntu 12.04 with cloud-init 0.6.3-0ubuntu1

My question is can I upgrade it to 0.7.5-0ubuntu1.1?

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/388273/392290) to a similar question for lucid might help

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: there is no supported path for running versions of cloud-init newer than 0.6.3-0ubuntu1 on Ubuntu 12.04.

However, some information on the general process may help you out.

For currently supported versions of Ubuntu you can upgrade to the latest supported cloud-init with 'apt-get upgrade'.  At this point Ubuntu 12.04/precise is out of support, so this specific question is mostly no longer relevant.

In Ubuntu 12.04 and 14.04, cloud-init very much followed the standard [Stable Release Updates](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/StableReleaseUpdates) policy in Ubuntu.  We only backported bug fixes but left the major version the same.

In 16.04 and going forward in 18.04, we have an [exception](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/CloudinitUpdates) to the SRU process.  We are actively pulling back new versions which allows us to add new features and keep the same code base active on all Ubuntu releases > 16.04.

Comment: But you did not answer the question. Is there solution or not? We know that Ubuntu 12.04 is out of support.